# Android Preferences expand item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

Can i create a Preferences Layout with list of expandable items using Android Preferences Components?
Something like attached image
[image]

If i can not do this with Android Preferences Components, How i can create a layout like this (Just give me an idea)?

Comment: What do you want exactly?, so... why you don't create a standard `layout` with each elements?

Comment: @Aspicas Week days are static but shifts are not static items the users can add/remove shift.

Comment: You can implement a `custom ListView` and add your elements dynamically only when you press a `add shift` button.